RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string: b'lp'
I'm trying to create a plot with matplotlib using latex's font in the spyder environment, but I encounter the following error:
RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
b'lp'

Here is the full command invocation and its output:

latex -interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --output-directory=tmp9wd9wbgp d174ba5a1278c3ea3324ab2ddb79f45c.tex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.5 Portable) (preloaded format=latex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

Sorry, but C:\Users\uripa\anaconda3\Library\miktex\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\x64\latex.exe did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\uripa\anaconda3\Library\miktex\texmfs\data\miktex\log\latex.log

I have latex installed in PATH, and miktex installed in conda's PATH, but the error persists. I don't know what has changed, since I have been doing plots with this font for a long time now. Any help would be appreciated!

Did you try "The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again" If yes, what does it say?
